# How similar is sqlite to mysql iPhone

Tags: iphone, mysql, objective-c, database, sqlite

I was just thinking about databases on the iPhone, and I wondered what I need to know to code sqlite on the iPhone. What are its similarities and differences to MySQL?

Thanks

Comment: Related: [FMDB](https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb) is an Objective-C wrapper around SQLite which makes working in SQLite much more tolerable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a really good comparison site for different SQL dialects:

- http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/SQL_Dialects_Reference

To quickly summarize the differences, here are a few:

**MySQL**

- Requires a username and password to connect.
- Identifiers are escaped by `
- Concatenates two strings with CONCAT()

Utilizes the following join types:

- CROSS
- INNER
- LEFT
- LEFT OUTER
- RIGHT
- RIGHT OUTER
- NATURAL
- NATURAL LEFT
- NATURAL LEFT OUTER
- NATURAL RIGHT
- NATURAL RIGHT OUTER
- STRAIGHT

Utilizes the following set operators:

- UNION
- UNION ALL
- UNION DISTINCT

**SQLite**

- Does not require a username and password to connect.
- Identifier are escaped by []
- Concatenates two string with ||

Utilizes the following join types:

- CROSS
- INNER
- LEFT
- LEFT OUTER
- NATURAL
- NATURAL CROSS
- NATURAL INNER
- NATURAL LEFT
- NATURAL LEFT OUTER

Utilizes the following set operators:

- EXCEPT
- INTERSECT
- UNION
- UNION ALL

There are some other differences when writing expression such as:

**MySQL**

- REGEX

**SQLite**

- REGEXP
- GLOB
- NOT GLOB
- MATCH
- NOT MATCH

To help you build queries, you can use https://github.com/ziminji/objective-c-sql-query-builder

If you want to compare the basic CRUD statements, here are some links to check out:

**MySQL**

- DELETE: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/delete.html
- INSERT: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert.html
- SELECT: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html
- UPDATE: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html

**SQLite**

- DELETE: http://www.sqlite.org/lang_delete.html
- INSERT: http://www.sqlite.org/lang_insert.html
- SELECT: http://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html
- UPDATE: http://www.sqlite.org/lang_update.html

Comment: Sorry about the exuberant edit summary. [I couldn't resist.](http://hyperboleandahalf.blogspot.com/2010/06/this-is-why-ill-never-be-adult.html)

Answer (score 0):

the sql language is pretty similar but not identical.  The most annoying difference is
that in sqlite you can't get a count of the records that match a query.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can `SELECT count(*)` in sqlite.

Comment: @tc I am pretty sure he is referring to a row count on a result.

Answer (score 0):

If you know SQL, then SQLite is like piece of cake. You can make use of the plugin provided in Firefox for SQLite and kick start with SQLite.

Answer (score 0):

The SQL syntax is fairly similar across both implementations.  However, SQLLite is farther from being / accepting the full SQL language.  Last time I tried using SQLLite I was forced to convert a `RIGHT JOIN` to a `LEFT JOIN` by changing around the table order.

Answer (score 0):

use this url and use this concept .....

http://dblog.com.au/iphone-development-tutorials/iphone-sdk-tutorial-reading-data-from-a-sqlite-database/

http://www.code2design.com/tutorial/convert_mysql_tables_to_sqlite_tables#comment-4543